# Creating a 2 column layout where the right column is fluid, and the left column is fluid but it's left position is somewhat fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-float

https://jsfiddle.net/nynd8b4b/

There are purple blocks at the top and bottom of this example, representing a centered site.

I have a module I want to include on the page that spans full width, that are 60% / 40% (seen in the red and blue blocks).

So here is the question:

I want the red block to stay lined up with the purple blocks on the left side as the viewport expands and contracts. I do not know the height of the red & blue blocks, so please don't put any height on them. I can use any number of divs to achieve this.

Ideas? Ideally this works on modern browsers and IE10 and up.

Edit: I'll even take an absolute position answer now... I'd obviously prefer it if I didn't have to do that. Also here is a wireframe of a design that I need this implementation for: https://wireframe.cc/TkX5QF

**Html:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">centered content</div>
</div>
<div class="full-width">
   <div class="sixty"></div>
   <div class="forty"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">centered content</div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.container {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: purple;
   color: white;
}

.full-width {
overflow: hidden;
}

.sixty{
   width: 60%;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
   float: left;
}

.forty {
   width: 40%;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: blue;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the blue block to still exceed the width of the purple blocks on a wider screen? Or should they both be contained?

Comment: yes, because if I wanted to constrain both, I would simply use the container classes I used for the other divs.

Comment: Haha, sorry to underestimate you there. Sometimes people post on here who might not have thought of that... I've been fiddling around for a while, and I don't think it can be done with pure css if you need to have widths set in percentages. The only way to match that left margin responsively is to have it inside a similar container, which means your percentage widths will respect that container too. This is as close as I got: https://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/nynd8b4b/10/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/nynd8b4b/4/

```
<body onresize="marg()" onload="marg()">
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="content">centered content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="sixty" id="sixty"></div>
    <div class="forty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">centered content</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  function marg() {
    var p = document.getElementById("container");
    var style1 = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);
    var p2 = document.getElementById("sixty").offsetWidth;

    var margin = style1.marginLeft;
    document.getElementById("sixty").style.marginLeft = style1.marginLeft;
    document.getElementById("sixty").style.width = "calc(60% - " + style1.marginLeft + ")";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: it absolutely is, however is this impossible to do with css?

Comment: I'll even take an absolute position answer now, if I absolutely must.

Comment: Yeah, I can give you another answer in an hour or two. I am busy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set an absolute position to the left column?

Comment: From the post: "I do not know the height of the red & blue blocks".

Comment: that being said... what would the absolute position solution be? what would I set to the left column exactly